# How to reference pipe from template in component code

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-pipe

How to reference pipe from template in component code? 
In template

```
 <tr *ngFor="let score of scores
                        | filterScores:modelFilter.value:modelFilter.name">
```

I want to retrieve values from this custom pipe in component so I can use them in code.
If I add pipe in constructor I will create new pipe.

```
constructor(private filterScoresPipe: FilterScoresPipe) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call the `transform` method with the Pipe's instance.

```
let filterScoresPipe = new FilterScoresPipe();
filterScoresPipe.transform(input, agr1, arg2);
```

Comment: That way I am creating new pipe and not referencing the one from template. I want to retrieve filtered values from template.